# mysql: join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in my database:

(here is the simplified structure)

- Table 1: Bugs -> bug_id, component_id
- Table 2: Components -> id
- Table 3: Duplicates -> dupe, dupe_of (both these fields are bug_ids, and represents the master and slave relationship between bugs)

Here is the sample queries

select bugs.bug_id, components.name from bugs INNER JOIN components ON components.id = bugs.component_id where bug_id IN (332, 333); 

`+--------+----------------------+ 
| bug_id | name | 
+--------+----------------------+ 
| 332 | Completion and Event | 
| 333 | Completion and Event | 
+--------+----------------------+`

select dupe from duplicates where dupe_of = 1016; 

`+------+ 
| dupe | 
+------+ 
| 322 | 
| 333 | 
+------+`

And i want something like with the second query

`+------+ 
| dupe | Name
+------+ 
+--------+----------------------+ 
| 332 | Completion and Event | 
| 333 | Completion and Event | 
+--------+----------------------+`

I don't understand how I can achieve this, because there is no direct relation between duplicates table and components table. Is it possible to form a Join so that I make use of bugs table in between and filter the final list of bugs?

Comment: Once you join `Components` and `Bugs`, then you can join `Bugs` and `Duplicates`.  `SELECT ... FROM Components JOIN Bugs ON component_id = Components.id JOIN Duplicates ON bug_id = dupe`

Comment: can you provide some data, so that it gets more clear.

Comment: if want the output like that table

Comment: ``select bugs.bug_id, components.name from bugs INNER JOIN components ON components.id = bugs.component_id where bug_id IN (332, 333);
 +--------+----------------------+
    | bug_id | name                 |
    +--------+----------------------+
    |    332 | Completion and Event |
    |    333 | Completion and Event |
    +--------+----------------------+
select dupe from duplicates where dupe_of = 1016;
    +------+
    | dupe |
    +------+
    |  322 |
    |  333 |
    +------+`code`

Comment: I dont know the format is going wrong.. basically i have give two sqls. First sql shows thre relation between components and bugs table. Second one shows the duplicates table. I want to show the corresponding component for the 322 and 333 in second query